# detecting a user-modified vs a js-modified input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 1 input that requires two different type of methods to be called when the input value is changed 1st by javascript and 2nd by the user.

Any clues on how I could differentiate these types of changes to the input?

Comment: Values changed through JavaScript do not trigger the `change` event (or any event).

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is that you should create a function for changing the field via javascript and have every piece of javascript that wants to change the field go through that function rather than changing the object directly.  Then, you can implement your JS-modification code in the function and know that any other changes are user changes.

If there's some reason you can't do that, then all I know you can do is to detect user changes through various events (keys, drag/drop, copy/paste, focus, blur, etc...) and somehow differentiate those from changes that aren't associated with the user.

If you perhaps described what problem you're really trying to solve, we could likely offer some other ideas.